# Installing Ruby 2.6 on Ubuntu 18.04 - bundler path error

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, rubygems, ubuntu-18.04, ruby-2.6

I've installed Ruby 2.6.6 on Ubuntu 18.04 using the following commands:

```
wget http://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.6/ruby-2.6.6.tar.gz
tar -xzvf ruby-2.6.6.tar.gz
cd ruby-2.6.6/
./configure
sudo make install
```

`ruby -v` confirms 2.6.6 installed.

But then when I run `gem install bundler` I get the error `/usr/bin/gem: no such file or directory`

Before installing Ruby 2.6.6 I removed version 2.5 using `sudo apt-get purge ruby`, so I'm wondering if the paths need re-configuring. I'm new to Ruby so I'm a bit lost. Any guidance please?

`which ruby` returns /usr/local/bin/ruby

I've found the gem directory in `/usr/local/bin/gem` how do I re-configure the gem path reference from `/usr/bin/gem` to `/usr/local/bin/gem`?

Comment: I would recommend using rbenv or installing ruby via snap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My first though would be that the path for gem is cached (as it seems like `/usr/local/bin` is in your PATH). Try to restart the shell and check this for more details: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5609/how-do-i-clear-bashs-cache-of-paths-to-executables

However, I think you should install Ruby (and in general any other software) from your distro repositories. Otherwise you won't get updates and your package manager may override/break the software later on (as the package manager is unaware of the changes). To do this for Ruby:

```
sudo apt install ruby-full
```

It seems like this will install Ruby 2.5.1. Check [packages.ubuntu](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/ruby) for details.

In case you need to install a different Ruby version (for example 2.6), I recommend you to use Rbenv + ruby-build. Check the following guide for more details about how to install Ruby in Ubuntu: https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-ruby-on-ubuntu-18-04

Comment: I'm confused by the different install options, perhaps I should remove and re-install. How would I specify the specific version with `sudo apt install ruby-full`?

Comment: You can not. I updated the answer with more details. Try to restart your shell, as it looks to me as the paths is cached and your installation is actually working.

Comment: Running `gem install bundler` after restarting the shell worked! Thank you Ana for you helpful advice and links.